# Issue with if statement query, eclipse saying "dead code"

Tags: java, date, loops, calendar, if-statement

First of all, ANY help that people can offer is very much appreciated!

OK, so I have this loop here, and I seem to be having a problem with the if statement.

Eclipse is telling me that the part of the query below AND the code within the "else" is "dead code":

```
|| calDateOfDay.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY
```

But I don't know why.

Also, when it executes, it ALWAYS executes the code inside the "if" statement, which (to my understanding) would mean that every day is a Saturday. However I know for a fact that the days have their correct value (that there are definitely days being checked that are NOT Saturdays). I know this as I have debugged through the code in Eclipse, checking the values of the days one by one.

Honestly I'm confused even trying to explain it! :S

What I would like the code to do is:

1. take each day that it gets (a months worth, differs depending on the month obv) and check to see if the day is a Saturday or a Sunday.
2. If it is a Saturday or Sunday then I want it to set the "type" of the day to weekend, and if not I want it to set the "type" of day to weekday.

That's basically it.

```
        for (DayEntry dayEntry : daySet){

            //day value to be filled
            Day day = new Day();
            Calendar calDateOfDay = new GregorianCalendar();
            //set the date of the day
            calDateOfDay.setTime(dayEntry.getDateOfDay());
            day.setDate(calDateOfDay);

            //set the hours of the day
            day.setWorkHours(dayEntry.getHours());

            if (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SATURDAY || Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY ){

                day.setType(DayType.WEEK_END);

            }else{

                day.setType(DayType.WEEK_DAY);

            }


            //add the day to the week
            week.addDay(day);   

        }
```

NOW, the reason I have the code written the way above is because when I had it written as below, Eclipse was telling me that I should be accessing the static variable `DAY_OF_WEEK` in a static way, so I'm also not sure if this is causing a problem.

```
        for (DayEntry dayEntry : daySet){

            //day value to be filled
            Day day = new Day();
            Calendar calDateOfDay = new GregorianCalendar();
            //set the date of the day
            calDateOfDay.setTime(dayEntry.getDateOfDay());
            day.setDate(calDateOfDay);

            //set the hours of the day
            day.setWorkHours(dayEntry.getHours());

            if (calDateOfDay.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SATURDAY || calDateOfDay.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY ){

                day.setType(DayType.WEEK_END);

            }else{

                day.setType(DayType.WEEK_DAY);

            }


            //add the day to the week
            week.addDay(day);   

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DAY_OF_WEEK`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) is a constant containing the *field number* for the day of the week. Your code uses it as if it contained the *value* of that field, which it doesn't.

To fix the code, simply replace `calDateOfDay.DAY_OF_WEEK` with `calDateOfDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is a static variable that stores an integer that refers to a field in an instance of Calendar which contains which day of the week it is.

What you want to do is `calDateOfDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
|| calDateOfDay.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY
```

This means that the first part of the boolean statement is evaluated by the compiler to be ALWAYS true.

Answer (score 0):

The constants [Calendar.SATURDAY](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SATURDAY) and
[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) are just `static final int` with value `7.` Therefore `calDateOfDay.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SATURDAY` is always `true`.

You need to check the appropriate field with [Calendar.get(int field)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) like

```
calDateOfDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)== Calendar.SATURDAY
```

etc.